# Cordova deep linking using firebase

Tags: android, cordova, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links, cordova-plugin-fcm

I am working on cordova project and I need to build deep linking using Google Firebase.

Currently I create links in firebase console and copy that link open in the mobile (where app is already installed) then my app is opened.

Now I need fire an event or catch the event when app is opened using firebase links so that I can redirect user to a particular page of app.

How Can I catch or fire event in cordova when firebase links is opened in the mobile ?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use a cordova plugin like "[cordova-plugin-firebase-dynamiclinks](https://github.com/chemerisuk/cordova-plugin-firebase-dynamiclinks)"